# Subversion Ignoring Configuration?

Tags: svn

After installing subversion 1.6.17 earlier today I followed this guide in setting up subversion on my server:

http://www.tonyspencer.com/2007/03/02/setup-a-subversion-server-in-4-minutes/

(For those who may worry I also did add the realm in the configuration.)

However, while using Dreamweaver, I was able to download all the files from the repo, but continue to get bad authentication (170001) when commiting files back. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

So far the most I've tried has been chmodding the whole repo folder to 777 to ensure everything has access to it.

EDITS:

I am using Dreamweaver CS5.5 with svn 1.6.9 built in.

On another note, in the guide when it says I should be prompted for username and password, I was not.

Comment: What version of Dreamweaver? Dreamweaver uses a built-in svn, not the binary installed on your computer and it [may be incompatible](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/770156) with the version of svn you've installed as the server.

Comment: I am using Dreamweaver CS5.5 and it's built in is 1.6.9.

Comment: Those should be compatible. I'd try first checking in with the command line client and make sure that works. I'm wondering if DW isn't handling the [auth notice](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#auth-related-improvements) properly.